# tensorflow consumes too much memory when using tf.map_fn

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
    @tf.function
    def c(self, point_instances, instances, alpha):
        def inner_comp(j):
            print(j.shape)
            print(tf.transpose(instances).shape)
            print(alpha.shape)
            print(tf.linalg.matvec(tf.transpose(instances), alpha).shape)
            tmp = tf.tensordot(j, tf.linalg.matvec(tf.transpose(instances), alpha), 1)
            print(tmp.shape)
            return tmp

        return tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(tf.map_fn(inner_comp, point_instances)))
```

I noticed that when `tf.map_fn` finishes the second iteration, it gets killed due to memory shortage. So the console output would be like:

```
(245245,)
(245245, 460)
(460,)
(245245,)
()

(245245,)
(245245, 1040)
(1040,)
(245245,)
()


Killed
```

Although my data is a large-scale, the output of `inner_comp` is always a scalar. I tried to allocate 200 GB of memory but still it gets killed. What would be the reason?